# the result button wont work I am trying to make program for conditional statement but my codes are not working

Tags: javascript, html

the condition are:
if number 1 is less than number 2 result should be addition
else if number 1 is greater than 2 result should be substraction
else if number 1 is equal to number 2 result should be multiplication
else if number 1 is divisible number 2 the result should be division.

javascript: calculate two numbers

```
    <script>
        
        function ();
        {
            var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
            var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);
           
            
            if(n1 > n2)
            {
                document.getElementById('result').value = n1+n2;
            }
            
            if(n1 < n2)
            {
                document.getElementById('result').value = n1-n2;
            }
            
            if(n1 == n2)
            {
                document.getElementById('result').value = n1/n2;
            }
            
            if(n1%2)
            {
                document.getElementById('result').value = n1*n2;
            }
        }
        
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="text" id="n1"/><br/><br/>
    
    <input type="text" id="n2"/><br/><br/>
    
    <button onclick="();">=</button>
    
    <input type="text" id="result"/>
    
</body>
```

Comment: thank you, i already fix the codes, however im having hard time about modulo,,, I cant seen to make the last part of condition work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your function to call it like that

`<button onclick="();">=</button>` doesn't mean anything

```js
    function calculate()
        {
            var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
            var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);
            console.log(n1, n2)
            
            if(n1 > n2)
            {
                document.getElementById('result').value = n1+n2;
            }
            
            if(n1 < n2)
            {
                document.getElementById('result').value = n1-n2;
            }
            
            if(n1 == n2)
            {
                document.getElementById('result').value = n1/n2;
            }
            
            if(n1%2)
            {
                document.getElementById('result').value = n1*n2;
            }
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1"/><br/><br/>
    
    <input type="text" id="n2"/><br/><br/>
    
    <button onclick="calculate();">=</button>
    
    <input type="text" id="result"/>
```